# stanford cs193p - PrintIntrospectionInfo - section 4 assignment 1b

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cs193p

I'm having trouble with section 4 of the stanford iphone class on assignment 1b.

I am having trouble understanding how I will build the array and what
the assignment expects.

Should the array be a "global" variable?  Where should I define that?
Will each of the other subfunctions add their variables to the array?
Is the PrintIntrospectionInfo function just there to enumerate through
and print all introspective info?

Where can I read up on the things they are asking for in this
assignment?  What should I read up on?

I'm not taking the class so can someone send me their code?  The
lessons build up on each other and I want to be able to proceed.

Here's the assignment :

> Objective-C has a number of facilities that add to its dynamic object-oriented capabilities.  Many 
>   of these facilities deal with determining and using an object's capabilities at runtime.  
>   Create a mutable array and add objects of various types to it.  Create instance of the classes 
>   we’ve used elsewhere in this assignment to populate the array:  NSString, NSURL, NSProcessInfo, 
>   NSDictionary, etc.  Create some NSMutableString instances and put them in the array as well.
>   Feel free to create other kinds of objects also.
>   Iterate through the objects in the array and do the following: 
>   1. Print the class name of the object. 
>   2. Log if the object is member of class NSString. 
>   3. Log if the object is kind of class NSString. 
>   4. Log if the object responds to the selector "lowercaseString". 
>   Page 5 of 6
>   5. If the object does respond to the lowercaseString selector, log the result of asking the 
>   object to perform that selector (using performSelector:) 
>   CS193P  Assignment 1B 
>   Spring 2009  Doll/Cannistraro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answers in cocoa and objective-c manuals that come with Xcode.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void printIntrospectionInfo()
{
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    [array addObject: [NSString stringWithString:@"Example NSString object"]];
    [array addObject: [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Example NSMutableString object"]];
    [array addObject: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com.au"]];
    [array addObject: [NSProcessInfo processInfo]];
    [array addObject: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"DictObject" forKey: @"KeyObject"]];
    [array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456]];

    SEL sel_lowercase = @selector(lowercaseString);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i)
    {
        id o = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"%@", o);
        NSLog(@"Class name: %@", [[o class] className]);
        NSLog(@"Is Member of NSString: %@", ([o isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]] ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
        NSLog(@"Is Kind of NSString: %@", ([o isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
        NSLog(@"Responds to lowercaseString: %@", ([o respondsToSelector: sel_lowercase] ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

        if ([o respondsToSelector: sel_lowercase])
            NSLog(@"lowercaseString: %@", [o performSelector: sel_lowercase]);

        NSLog(@"===================");
    }

}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    printIntrospectionInfo();
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good example.  You probably want to replace [o respondsToSelector: @selector(lowercaseString)] with [o respondsToSelector: lowercase]

Comment: Thank you!  I see you interpreted the assignment differently.  But that's great.  It's a demonstration of exactly the kind of thing they want you to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The first assignment wasn't so much about design as it was about feeling around Objective-C.  A global variable is fine, but a local variable would be much easier.

Comment: In this case, how do I create the global variable?  It's only a .m file.

Also, what pdfs (and pages) should I read?  Or online doc?

Comment: It's very much like C if you're familiar with that.  You can do something as simple as:

NSArray * array; (or NSMutableArray if need be)

Comment: Where?  Outside the main function?

Comment: You can place it there if you want, but anywhere really.

Comment: Outside any function would be file scope—a global. Inside a function would be a local.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I read up on the things they are asking for in this assignment? What should I read up on?

Aside from the local-vs.-global issue (locals are better), read the [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/) docs. All four questions pertain to things you'll do with methods implemented by NSObjects.

Don't forget to also read up on [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/).

Comment: That NSObject doc looks useful.

Comment: All of the framework class references are. It's worth downloading the docs and then bookmarking your local copies of the Foundation and AppKit (Mac)/UIKit (iPhone) framework references for easy access from your browser.